# How do I expose a custom API permission in Azure B2C? Only admins are supported

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm following the [B2C directions here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/README-incremental-instructions.md) to secure my API, however the Azure B2C portal doesn't expose this feature fully. Instead it only allows for Admin consent, not user consent.

[image of portal missing end user prompts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v2Vp.png)

- Is this feature fully supported?
- Why would there be an admin scope and not an end user scope?
- What scenarios is this custom permission expected to be used within, and am I trying to do something unexpected with B2C?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are configure [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C) with your Azure AD B2C, you should follow this [README](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/README.md) file rather than [B2C directions here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/README-incremental-instructions.md).

The link you are following is not for Azure AD B2C. It should be for Azure AD.

I'm not sure why it's put into this path. Have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/329).

Based on [Add a web API application to your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application?tabs=app-reg-preview#configure-scopes), user consent is not mentioned. I think it's not supported currently.

Comment: I was having exact same issue. Thanks for the link since all the documentation is all over the place and outdated as well.